# scrape element which is preceded by specific element using beautifulsoup and css selector instead of lxml and xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want to scrape the 'Services/Products' section from this page: https://www.yellowpages.com/deland-fl/mip/ryan-wells-pumps-20533306?lid=1001782175490

The text is inside a dd element that always come after the element

Services/Products

I created the code to scrape this text, using lxml and xpath:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = ""
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
session = requests.Session()

r = session.get(url, timeout=30, headers=headers)
t = html.fromstring(r.content)

products = t.xpath('//dd[preceding-sibling::dt[contains(.,"Services/Products")]]/text()[1]')[0] if t.xpath('//dd[preceding-sibling::dt[contains(.,"Services/Products")]]') else ''
```

Is there is any way to get the same text using Beautifulsoup (and css selector if possible) instead of lxml and xpath ?

Answer (score 0):

Try working with BeautifulSoup and Requests. It's a lot easier.
Here's some code

```
# BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser. You can find specific elements in a BeautifulSoup object
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/deland-fl/mip/ryan-wells-pumps-20533306?lid=1001782175490"


obj = BeautifulSoup(get(url).content, "html.parser")

# Gets the section with the Services
buisness_info = obj.find("section", {"id":"business-info"})

# Getting all <dd> elements (cause you can pick off the one you need from the list)
all_dd = buisness_info.find_all("dd")

# Finds the specific tag with the text you need
services_and_products = all_dd[2]

# Gets the text
text = services_and_products.text

# All Done
print(text)
```

Comment: I don't want to get elements by position, all_dd[2] will not work on other pages because position is different from page to page

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on your pages:

```
inf = soup.select_one('section#business-info dl')
target = inf.find("dt", text='Services/Products').nextSibling
for t in target.stripped_strings:
    print(t)
```

Output:

```
Pumps|Well Pumps|Residential Pumps|Water Pumps|Residential Pumps|Well Pumps|Residential Pumps|Commercial Pumps|Well Pumps|Pumps & Water Tanks|Residential & Commercial|Residential & Commercial|Water Tanks|Pump Maintenance|Pump Maintenance|Free Estimates|Service & Repair|Emergency Service Avail|Residential & Commercial|Service & Repair|Residential & Commercial|Pumps|Bonded|Insured|Water Tanks|Deep Wells|4 Wells|Pumps & Water Tanks 4'' Wells|2' - 12' Diameter Wells
```